# Is it Safe editing the CronTab with PHP?

Tags: php, security, cron, cron-task

I'm building a script thanks to [this tuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/) to append and remove cronjob from the admin part of a website made with php.

Is it safe to implement it on the server ? What could be the issues ?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't really belong here

Comment: Cronjob is to be updated with `crontab -e` command. I do not know what can really happen if you access to `/etc/crontab` directly, but it is always recommended not to do like that.

Comment: Don't add anything user-supplied into the crontab definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that:

List of script in your crontab (f.e.):

```
#script1
#script2
#script3
```

I'm removing script from crontab:

```
crontab -l | grep -v "#script1" > crontab.txt && crontab crontab.txt
```

List of script in your crontab after edit:

```
#script2
#script3
```

Command `crontab -l | grep -v "#script1" > crontab.txt && crontab crontab.txt` you can run from `exec()` function.

I hope I helped.